# Use Linq to search through list

Tags: c#, sql, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

Is it possible to use a Linq query to search through a `List`? In my web app I have to potentially process over 14k records based upon a spreadsheet uploaded by the user. With each record processed, I need to compare that record against what we currently have in our database in order to make sure we either aren't adding a duplicate or I know what record I need to be updating/editing.

Instead of hitting the database 14k times or more, I wanted to pull all the records contained on this table into a `List`, and then perform a search based on a set of conditions.

Here is the Linq query I currently have that hits the database. The business rules are pretty... complicated so I won't bother you with the details but these are the conditions that I need to satisfy for the search. I've tested this query and it returns the expected results.

```
var previousZips = (from z in db.ZipCodeTerritory
                    where (item.ZipCode.Equals(null) ?
                            z.StateCode.Equals(item.StateCode) &&
                            z.ChannelCode.Equals(item.ChannelCode) &&
                            SqlFunctions.DateDiff("DAY", z.EndDate, item.EndDate) == 0 :
                            z.StateCode.Equals(item.StateCode) &&
                            z.ChannelCode.Equals(item.ChannelCode) &&
                            SqlFunctions.DateDiff("DAY", z.EndDate, item.EndDate) == 0 &&
                            (z.ZipCode.Equals(null) || z.ZipCode.Equals(item.ZipCode)))
                    select z).ToList();
```

What I would like to do, however, is create a `List` of all the records on the table like this:

```
List<ZipCodeTerritory> allRecords = (from z in db.ZipCodeTerritory
                                        select z).ToList()
```

and then use a query similar to this to pull the record I'm looking for from the list:

```
List<ZipCodeTerritory> previousZips = allRecords.Where(
                                        z => (item.ZipCode.Equals(null)
                                        ? z.StateCode.Equals(item.StateCode) &&
                                        z.ChannelCode.Equals(item.ChannelCode) &&
                                        SqlFunctions.DateDiff("DAY", z.EndDate,
                                            item.EndDate) == 0
                                        : z.StateCode.Equals(item.StateCode) &&
                                        z.ChannelCode.Equals(item.ChannelCode) &&
                                        SqlFunctions.DateDiff("DAY", z.EndDate,item.EndDate) == 0 &&
                                        (z.ZipCode.Equals(null) || z.ZipCode.Equals(item.ZipCode))
                                    )
                            ).ToList();
```

The query above (from the `List`), however, throws the following error:

```
This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities.
```

Comment: I'd say the error message is fairly straightforward.  If you want to do all of that logic in linq to objects, rather than on the DB end, then you'll need to use a different tool than `SqlFunctions`.

Comment: Yup. Realized that right after I posted. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Answered my own question. The problem here was the `SqlFunction`. By removing that from the query and re-writing it like this it works

```
List<ZipCodeTerritory> previousZips = allRecords.Where(
                                        z => (item.ZipCode.Equals(null)
                                        ? z.StateCode.Equals(item.StateCode) &&
                                        z.ChannelCode.Equals(item.ChannelCode) &&
                                        z.EndDate.Date == item.EndDate.Date
                                        : z.StateCode.Equals(item.StateCode) &&
                                        z.ChannelCode.Equals(item.ChannelCode) &&
                                        z.EndDate.Date == item.EndDate.Date &&
                                        (z.ZipCode.Equals(null) || z.ZipCode.Equals(item.ZipCode))
                                    )
                            ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`SqlFunctions.DateDiff("DAY", z.EndDate,item.EndDate) == 0`

use

```
z.EndDate.Subtract(item.EndDate).TotalDays == 0
```

Comment: Note that `TotalDays` is a double, not an integer.  Half a days difference will be 0.5, not 0, so the code you showed is essentially just asking if the dates are equal, not within a day of each other.  There are much easier (and more importantly, clearer) ways of comparing for equality, like, say, `Equals` or `==`.